# Trouble dealing with POSIXct timezones and truncating the time out of POSIXct objects

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have the following piece of R-code:

```
formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
x = as.POSIXct(strptime("2013-11-23 23:10:38.000000", formatString))
y = as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-07-17 01:43:38.000000", formatString))
```

I have the problem that when I do `as.Date(y)` then I get `2015-07-16` (although its date is one day later!). Apparently the problem is the timezone. So I checked the timezones:

```
> x
[1] "2013-11-23 23:10:38 CET"
> y
[1] "2015-07-17 01:43:38 CEST"
>
```

Ok, so they deviate in their timezone. This is weird, because why does R decide that one timestamp (given without any timezone at all) lies in a different timezone than another (given without any timezone at all)?

Ok, so lets set the timezone. Googling revealed that `attr(y, "tzone") <- "CET"` should do the deal. Lets try this:

```
> attr(y, "tzone") <- "CET"
> y
[1] "2015-07-17 01:43:38 CEST"
>
```

Ok, that did not work. Let see what the timezone actually is in the beginning:

```
> formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
> x = as.POSIXct(strptime("2013-11-23 23:10:38.000000", formatString))
> y = as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-07-17 01:43:38.000000", formatString))
> unclass(x)
[1] 1385244638
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
> unclass(y)
[1] 1437090218
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
>
```

So... they dont have a timezone at all but their timezones are different????

--> here are my natural questions:

1) why are they initialized with a different timezone when I dont specify a timezone at all?

2) why do both objects apparently not have a timezone and at the same time... how come they have different timezones?

3) How can I make `as.Date(y) == "2015-07-17"` true? I.e. how can I set both to the current timezone? `Sys.timezone()` results in 'NA'... (EDIT: my timezone [Germany] seems to be "CET" --> how can I set both to CET?)

I'm scratching my head here... Thanks for any thoughts on this you share with me :-)

FW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a timezone then R will use your system's locale as POSIXct objects must have a timezone.  The difference between CEST and CET is that one is summertime and one is not.  That means if you define a date during the part of the year defined as summertime then R will decide to use the summertime version of the timezone.  If you want to set dates that don't use summertime versions then define them as GMT from the beginning.

```
formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
x = as.POSIXct(strptime("2013-11-23 23:10:38.000000", formatString), tz="GMT")
y = as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-07-17 01:43:38.000000", formatString), tz="GMT")
```

If you want to truncate out the time, don't use `as.Date` on a POSIXct object since `as.Date` is meant to convert character objects to Date objects (which aren't the same as POSIXct objects).  If you want to truncate POSIXct objects with base R then you'll have to wrap either `round` or `trunc` in `as.POSIXct` but I would recommend checking out the `lubridate` package for dealing with dates and times (specifically POSIXct objects).

If you want to keep CET but never use CEST you can use a location that doesn't observe daylight savings.  According to http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet your only options are Algeria and Tunisia.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones the valid tz would be "Africa/Algiers".  Therefore you could do

```
 formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
x = as.POSIXct(strptime("2013-11-23 23:10:38.000000", formatString), tz="Africa/Algiers")
y = as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-07-17 01:43:38.000000", formatString), tz="Africa/Algiers")
```

and both x and y would be in CET.

One more thing about setting timezones.  If you tell R you want a generic timezone then it won't override daylight savings settings.  That's why setting `attr(y, "tzone") <- "CET"` didn't have the desired result.  If you did `attr(y, "tzone") <- "Africa/Algiers"` then it would have worked as you expected.  Do be careful with conversions though because when you change the timezone it will change the time to account for the new timezone.  The package `lubridate` has the function `force_tz` which changes the timezone without changing the time for cases where the initial timezone setting was wrong but the time was right.

Comment: Edit: I dont understand :( If the daylight saving time is the problem how come that R made another *day* out of it? Shouldnt it just vary by +-1 hour then? Also, before reading your post I just went with the timezone "Europe". Now as.Date seems to work as desired. Does that mean that the timezone "Europe" does not know about daylight saving time?

Comment: R will let you define the timezone as anything even if it isn't recognized from this list https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones.  I'm not sure what unexpected behavior might happen if you don't use something from the list.  It could work as expected for all cases or you might end up with a bug one day for a particular edge case.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I meant I used "Europe/Berlin" (which is valid)... I now understand what happens: as.Date just strips off the timzone (which then results basically in an integer, namely the amount of seconds after Jan 1st 1970 00:00:00 [in the same timezone]) meaning that for y we get a number a such that "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+2" + a = "2015-07-07 01:43:38 UTC+2". Then as.Date just tells R to take the date part of ("1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC+0" + a/24*60*60) = date of ("2015-07-16 23:43:38 UTC+0") = "2015-07-16". So the _silent_ switch of timezones causes the behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be/have been confused... it does not work with 'Europe/Berlin' either... Question is answered... im too stupid to cope with the strange date time business and give up my job :-)

Answer (score 1):

Complementary answer:

1) Just use the right timezone throughout from the beginning. Since I live in Hamburg, Germany, the right timezone for me is "Europe/Berlin", see [this list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as said by Dean.

2) For extracting information from POSIXct, for example, the date, I use

```
as.Date(format(timeStamp, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

which is slow but seems to give the correct answer... plus I dont have to install new packages [which is a bit complicated in my situation].

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found your Question here.

While all the given answers are valid and get an upvote from me, I'd like to share another - not too elegant - but working solution:

When ever you want to transform from class 'Date' to 'POSIXct' or vice versa, use as.character() before you convert:

```
x = as.POSIXct("2022-01-01")
y = as.POSIXct("2022-06-01")

x_Date <- as.Date(x)
x_POSIXct_again <- as.POSIXct(x_Date)
identical(x, x_POSIXct_again)
# FALSE!

y_Date <- as.Date(y)
y_POSIXct_again <- as.POSIXct(y_Date)
identical(y, y_POSIXct_again)
# FALSE!

x_Date <- as.Date(as.character(x))
x_POSIXct_again <- as.POSIXct(as.character(x_Date))
identical(x, x_POSIXct_again)
# TRUE!

y_Date <- as.Date(as.character(y))
y_POSIXct_again <- as.POSIXct(as.character(y_Date))
identical(y, y_POSIXct_again)
# TRUE!

# little helpers
as_Date2 <- function(x, ...) {
  if("POSIXct" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x)
  as.Date(x, ...)
}

as_POSIXct2 <- function(x, ...) {
  if("Date" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x)
  as.POSIXct(x, ...)
}
```

Obviously - time information gets lost when converting from POSIXct to DATE. But no more day-switching at last.